# nodejs bcrypt Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 51

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, bcrypt

I have tried all the solutions given in the other answers but still getting this error. 
I have removed node modules and reinstalled(with sudo and without). tried `npm rebuild`.
 `package.json` node version and running node version is same.

**node version 7.7.2**

**npm version 4.3.0**

```
[ E 2017-12-15 10:46:18.1523 17709/Tf age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/travelapp/public_html: An error occurred w$
  Error ID: f5a8c564
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-p5PoAx.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read$
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
<pre>
module.js:435
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 51.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:435:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/var/www/travelapp/public_html/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you launch application with the same node version that you use to install packages?

Comment: yes.. console.log(process.version); is same as node --version

Comment: May be you use/copy some precompiled packages? Also it's possible that you use some global modules which were installed by different node version. Also, please try `npm clean cache && npm install`